# Jenkins - restrict where this project can be run option with && (and) option fails

Tags: jenkins

I have a master and two slaves. When i want a job to run on both the salves i put in this expression in the `Restrict where this project can be run option`

```
linux && linux2
```

I have labelled the nodes correctly. But then the jobs dont run on any machines. I get an error such as `Theres no slave/cloud that matches this assignment` and the the job is still pending saying it cannot find a label matching the expression. Whats wrong? How can i make it run on both slaves. I do not want to use any other plugin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your expression says that a machine must have two labels: `linux` **and** `linux2`.

You most likely want to say `linux` **or** `linux2`, which would be `linux || linux2`.
That would mean, when you start a build, that it runs on either one of those two machines.

If you want the build to occur on **both** machines when you start a build, you could install the [Node Label Parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin), mark your job as "This project is parameterized", add a "Node" parameter, choosing `linux` and `linux2` under "Default nodes", and then choose "Execute concurrent builds if necessary", so that builds can happen on both machines at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the answer. I am aware of this Node Label Parameter plugin, but first I wanted to confirm whether there was an option of doing it with this restrict option. But it seems there isn't. The help option in Jenkins was sort of misleading me. They showed the `&&` operator and I assumed it would get my job done.

Comment: The help in Jenkins should be pretty clear, as I recently rewrote it ;)  A build runs on one machine at a time, and the expression defines which labels a particular node needs to have in order to start a build (e.g. "linux *and* mysql", so "machine1 *and* machine2" wouldn't make sense).  But please do file a bug if you feel it's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to remove the spaces in your label expression?

On my Jenkins instance, we are using this kind of expression and it's working well:

[image]

Comment: Whitespace isn't significant in label expressions.

Answer (score 0):

That didnt work for me I get "No agent/cloud matches this label expression. "

I found the correct syntax though:

This worked:
("Machine LABEL here") || ("Machine Label 2") here

Also check the LABEL of the Node as Jenkins displays the NAME and not the LABEL in the auto match results as you type. Yeah I know !!